# Unable to return Text in the type of ListItem

Tags: css, reactjs, list, react-native, listitem

I need to return the text of ParcelId in List format. I tried changing the Text next to View as ListItem, either i do not get the output or the style is not getting supported. I'm not sure how to wrap text in a list type,help needed. Thank you.

Code:

```
<View style={styles.MainContainerView}>
        <View style={styles.ChildView}>
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.7}
            onPress={this.expand_collapse_Function}>
            <Icon name="ios-arrow-dropdown"/>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <View style={{ height: this.state.updatedHeight, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
            <Text style={styles.ExpandViewInsideText} 
              onLayout={(value) => this.getHeight(value.nativeEvent.layout.height)}>
                 {
                   this.props.parcels.map((list,j) => {
                    console.log(" Parcel Id:"+list.parcelId)
                     return(
                           <Text key={j}>  {" Parcel Id:" + list.parcelId} </Text>
                     )
                   })
                 }
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that by wrapping view and text inside return as below:

```
 return(
     <View key={j} 
           style={{ height: this.state.updatedHeight, overflow: 'hidden' }}>

    <Text onLayout={(value)=this.getHeight(value.nativeEvent.layout.height)} 
          style={styles.ExpandViewInsideText}> 
          {" Parcel Id:" + list.parcelId}
    </Text> 
    </View>
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this, please note i have not tested this snippet.

```
const listOfParcel = this.props.parcels;

return(
    <div>
        {listOfParcel.map((list,j) => {
            <li key={j}>{list.parcelId}</li>
        })}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Thank you, the full content is not getting displayed. Trying to fix it.